# Why HTML "submit" not working?

Tags: html

I am making a Register - Login system in php/HTML and i have 3 php files now, in the first file (registering) worked FORM but in the second (login) not. The submit button don't do anything.  What can be the problem?

```html
<HMTL>
    <HEAD><h1>Bejelentkezés</h1></HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <body background="http://wallpaperstock.net/minimal-gray-to-white-gradient_wallpapers_33797_1440x900.jpg"
    <form action="afterlogin.php" method="post">
        Felhasználónév: <input type="text" name="user2">
        Jelszó: <input type="password" name="pass2">
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
    </BODY>
</HMTL>
```

Comment: Missing a `>` for `<body background="http://wallpaperstock.net/minimal-gray-to-white-gradient_wallpapers_33797_1440x900.jpg"` typo? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: There's no PHP code here, it's just plain HTML.

Comment: [*You're welcome...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680487/why-html-submit-not-working#comment45653770_28680487)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<html>
    <head><h1>Bejelentkezés</h1></head>
    <body background="http://wallpaperstock.net/minimal-gray-to-white-gradient_wallpapers_33797_1440x900.jpg">
    <form action="afterlogin.php" method="post">
        Felhasználónév: <input type="text" name="user2">
        Jelszó: <input type="password" name="pass2">
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

A lot of typo buddy...like `HMTL`..two `body` tags...plz do take care of what you write..and get some linting tool...

Answer (score 0):

You have body tag two times in your code,please make it single and close tag is also not there,please add that.